# Constrained Newton-Raphson estimation

Tags: r

I am trying to use a Newton-Raphson algorithm in `R` to minimize a log-likelihood function that I wrote for a very specific problem. I will say honestly that estimation methods are above my head, but I know that many people in my field (psychometrics) use NR algorithms for estimation, so I am trying to use this method, at least to begin with. I have a series of nested functions that return a scalar as the log-likelihood estimate for a particular vector of data:

```
log.likelihoodSL <- function(x,sxdat1,item) {
  theta <- x[1]
  rho <- x[2]
  log.lik <- 0
  for (it in 1:length(sxdat1)) {
    val <- as.numeric(sxdat1[it])
    apars <- item[it,1:3]
    cpars <- item[it,4:6]
    log.lik <- log.lik + as.numeric(log.pSL(theta,rho,apars,cpars,val))
  }
  return(log.lik)
}

log.pSL <- function(theta,rho,apars,cpars,val) {
  p <- (rho * e.aSL(theta,apars,cpars,val)) + ((1-rho) * e.nrm(theta,apars,cpars,val))
  log.p <- log(p)
  return(log.p)
}

e.aSL <- function(theta,apars,cpars,val) {
  if (val==1) {
    aprob <- e.nrm(theta,apars,cpars,val)
  } else if (val==2) {
    aprob <- 1 - e.nrm(theta,apars,cpars,val)
  } else
    aprob <- 0
  return(aprob)
}

e.nrm <- function(theta,apars,cpars,val) {
  nprob <- exp(apars*theta + cpars)/sum(exp((apars*theta) + cpars))
  nprob <- nprob[val]
  return(nprob)
}
```

Those functions all call each other in turn, in the order presented. The call to the highest function is as follows:

```
max1 <- maxNR(log.likelihoodSL,grad=NULL,hess=NULL,start=x,print.level=1,sxdat1=sxdat1,item=item)
```

Here is a sample of the input data (which I call `sxdat1` in this case):

```
> sxdat1
 V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 
  2   1   3   1   3   3   2   2   3   2   2   2   2   2   3   2   3   2 
V19 V20 
  2   2
```

And here is the variable `item`:

```
> item
             V1        V2         V3           V4         V5        V6
 [1,] 0.2494625 0.3785529 -0.6280155 -0.096817808 -0.7549263 0.8517441
 [2,] 0.2023690 0.4582290 -0.6605980 -0.191895013 -0.8391203 1.0310153
 [3,] 0.2044005 0.3019147 -0.5063152 -0.073135691 -0.6061725 0.6793082
 [4,] 0.2233619 0.4371988 -0.6605607 -0.160377714 -0.8233197 0.9836974
 [5,] 0.2257933 0.2851198 -0.5109131 -0.044494872 -0.5970246 0.6415195
 [6,] 0.2047308 0.3438725 -0.5486033 -0.104356236 -0.6693569 0.7737131
 [7,] 0.3402220 0.2724951 -0.6127172  0.050795183 -0.6639092 0.6131140
 [8,] 0.2513672 0.3263046 -0.5776718 -0.056203015 -0.6779823 0.7341853
 [9,] 0.2008285 0.3389165 -0.5397450 -0.103565987 -0.6589961 0.7625621
[10,] 0.2890680 0.2700661 -0.5591341  0.014251386 -0.6219001 0.6076488
[11,] 0.3127214 0.2572715 -0.5699929  0.041587479 -0.6204483 0.5788608
[12,] 0.2697048 0.2965255 -0.5662303 -0.020115553 -0.6470669 0.6671825
[13,] 0.2799978 0.3219374 -0.6019352 -0.031454750 -0.6929045 0.7243592
[14,] 0.2773233 0.2822723 -0.5595956 -0.003711768 -0.6314010 0.6351127
[15,] 0.2433519 0.2632824 -0.5066342 -0.014947878 -0.5774375 0.5923853
[16,] 0.2947281 0.3605812 -0.6553092 -0.049389825 -0.7619178 0.8113076
[17,] 0.2290081 0.3114185 -0.5404266 -0.061807853 -0.6388839 0.7006917
[18,] 0.3824588 0.2543871 -0.6368459  0.096053788 -0.6684247 0.5723709
[19,] 0.2405821 0.3903595 -0.6309416 -0.112333048 -0.7659758 0.8783089
[20,] 0.2424331 0.3028480 -0.5452811 -0.045311136 -0.6360968 0.6814080
```

The two parameters over which I want to minimize the function `log.likelihood()` are theta and rho, and I want to constrain theta to be between -3 and 3, and rho to be between 0 and 1, but I don't know how to do this with the current set-up. Can anybody help me out? Do I need to use a different estimation method from the Newton-Raphson method or is there a way to implement this using the function `maxNR`, which is from the package `maxLik`, that I am currently using? Thanks!

Edit: the vector `x`, which contains the start values for the parameters theta and rho, is just `c(0,0)` because that is the "average" or "default" assumption for these parameters (in terms of their substantive interpretation).

Comment: I write my own likelihoods all the time, but I have always used something like:  fit = optim(par=c(0.5,0,0), fn=negLL08, method='BFGS', hessian=TRUE) for estimation where negLL08 is the function that defines the log-likelihood.  I admit I am not sure how to constrain the parameters.  Yours is a very interesting post.

Comment: Consider using `optim` with the "BFGS" method, a *quasi-Newton method*. It handles upper and lower bounds.

Comment: @flodel: `method="BFGS"` doesn't but `method="L-BFGS-B"` does.  It looks like `maxNR` doesn't handle box constraints, but `library("sos"); findFn("Newton-Raphson box constraints")` finds the function `newton` in the `Bhat` package ...

Comment: on the other hand, `Bhat` has been archived ( ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/src/contrib/Archive/Bhat/ ) and might be a pain to get running (last version is 3 years old).

Comment: I actually did try to use `method="L-BFGS-B"` but I found that it didn't help much above using `maxNR`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data in a more convenient form:

```
sxdat1 <- c(2,1,3,1,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,2)
item <- matrix(c(
0.2494625,0.3785529,-0.6280155,-0.096817808,-0.7549263,0.8517441,
0.2023690,0.4582290,-0.6605980,-0.191895013,-0.8391203,1.0310153,
0.2044005,0.3019147,-0.5063152,-0.073135691,-0.6061725,0.6793082,
0.2233619,0.4371988,-0.6605607,-0.160377714,-0.8233197,0.9836974,
0.2257933,0.2851198,-0.5109131,-0.044494872,-0.5970246,0.6415195,
0.2047308,0.3438725,-0.5486033,-0.104356236,-0.6693569,0.7737131,
0.3402220,0.2724951,-0.6127172,0.050795183,-0.6639092,0.6131140,
0.2513672,0.3263046,-0.5776718,-0.056203015,-0.6779823,0.7341853,
0.2008285,0.3389165,-0.5397450,-0.103565987,-0.6589961,0.7625621,
0.2890680,0.2700661,-0.5591341,0.014251386,-0.6219001,0.6076488,
0.3127214,0.2572715,-0.5699929,0.041587479,-0.6204483,0.5788608,
0.2697048,0.2965255,-0.5662303,-0.020115553,-0.6470669,0.6671825,
0.2799978,0.3219374,-0.6019352,-0.031454750,-0.6929045,0.7243592,
0.2773233,0.2822723,-0.5595956,-0.003711768,-0.6314010,0.6351127,
0.2433519,0.2632824,-0.5066342,-0.014947878,-0.5774375,0.5923853,
0.2947281,0.3605812,-0.6553092,-0.049389825,-0.7619178,0.8113076,
0.2290081,0.3114185,-0.5404266,-0.061807853,-0.6388839,0.7006917,
0.3824588,0.2543871,-0.6368459,0.096053788,-0.6684247,0.5723709,
0.2405821,0.3903595,-0.6309416,-0.112333048,-0.7659758,0.8783089,
0.2424331,0.3028480,-0.5452811,-0.045311136,-0.6360968,0.6814080),
               byrow=TRUE,ncol=6)
```

Using `maxNR`:

```
library(maxLik)
x <- c(0,0)
max1 <- maxNR(log.likelihoodSL,grad=NULL,hess=NULL,start=x,
              print.level=1,sxdat1=sxdat1,item=item)
```

Note warnings incurred when `rho` wanders negative. However, `maxNR` can recover
from this and gets an estimate (theta=-1, rho=0.63) that is in the interior of
the feasible set.  `L-BFGS-B` can't handle non-finite interim results, but the bounds
keep it the algorithm away from those problematic regions.

I chose to do this with `bbmle` rather than in `optim`: `bbmle` is a wrapper for `optim` (and other optimization tools) that offers some nice features specific to likelihood estimation (profiling, confidence intervals, likelihood ratio tests between models, etc.).

```
library(bbmle)

## mle2() wants a NEGATIVE log-likelihood
NLL <- function(x,sxdat1,item) {
    -log.likelihoodSL(x,sxdat1,item)
}
```

**edit**: in an earlier version I used `control=list(fnscale=-1)` to tell the optimizer that I was passing a log-likelihood function that should be maximized rather than minimized; this gets to the right answer, but subsequent attempts to use the results might get very confusing because the package isn't accounting for this possiblity (e.g. the sign of the reported log-likelihood is wrong).  This could be fixed in the package, but I'm not sure it's worth it.

```
## needed when objective function takes a vector of args rather than
##  separate named arguments:
parnames(NLL) <- c("theta","rho")
(m1 <- mle2(NLL,start=c(theta=0,rho=0.5),method="L-BFGS-B",
     lower=c(theta=-3,rho=2e-3),upper=c(theta=3,rho=1-2e-3),
     data=list(sxdat1=sxdat1,item=item)))
```

A couple of points here:

- started at `rho=0.5` rather than on the boundary
- set the `rho` boundaries slightly inside [0,1] (`L-BFGS-B` doesn't always perfectly respect boundaries when computing finite difference approximations of derivatives)
- specified the input data in the `data` argument

In this case I get the same results as `maxNR`.

```
 ## Call:
 ## mle2(minuslogl = NLL, start = c(theta = 0, rho = 0.5), 
 ##     method = "L-BFGS-B", data = list(sxdat1 = sxdat1, item = item), 
 ##     lower = c(theta = -3, rho = 0.002), upper = c(theta = 3, 
 ##         rho = 1 - 0.002), control = list(fnscale = -1))
 ## 
 ## Coefficients:
 ##      theta        rho 
 ## -1.0038531  0.6352782 
 ## 
 ## Log-likelihood: -18.11
```

Unless you have a really burning need to do this with Newton-Raphson rather than with a gradient-based "quasi-Newton" method, I would guess that this is good enough. (It doesn't sound like you have strong technical reasons to do so, other than "that's what other people do in my field" -- a good reason, all other things being equal, but not enough in this case to make me dig around to implement N-R when similar methods are easily available and work fine.)

Comment: This is a great answer! I really look forward to trying out your suggestions, thanks so much! I saw a lot of stuff about gradient functions when I was trying to figure out how to do this, but I must admit I don't really understand what they are or how to implement them in a situation where I don't have a nice, neat little function. Also, thanks for the tip on `bbmle`

Comment: defining gradient functions explicitly is useful if you want to speed up your optimization or make it more robust, but for straightforward problems you can often do without them (and rely on the built-in numerical finite difference approximations). For really tough problems you might look into AD Model Builder ( http://www.admb-project.org )